# How To Fill-Up a particular field of HTML form Based On The Button Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment, static-site

I am making a Static Website with 5 kind of different home aomation service.

These are having different prices.

Whenever they click on "book now" button, A Booking form pops up.

Now, I want to fill up the "service required" field in the form automatically.

For Example if someone's clicking the book now button for "Full Home Automation Package" the "sevice required" will automatically be filled with that name.

How can i do so using html and JavaScript

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to give your button a function where you get your

text content and paste it to your Input, like this:

```js
function MyFunction(){
 var value = document.getElementById("Test").textContent; 
  document.getElementById("test2").value=value;
}
```

```html
<p id="Test"> Is this what you want ? </p>
<button type="button" onclick="MyFunction()">Click</button><br><br>
<input type = "text" id="test2" name "teste2">
```

Comment: I dont want to change the text I want top.put the text in the form Aautomatically. Is there any way to do that...??

Comment: Check if that's what you want, i edited the snippet, just run it and try it, give me your feedback if that's what you want.

Comment: No... I want to copy the text already present in <p> tag to the input field

Comment: Like that or without the button click ?

Comment: Ok I got it. Done. Thanks For You Help... 

Comment: If you need any explanation just ask for it, it was a pleasure to help

Comment: But As I Told I Have 5 Different Packages... So I would Have To Use The Same Scrip With different functions name and IDs again and again... Is there only one scrip for all type of packages...??

Comment: I Guess you can create a global js file with that function and try to work with the ID's, the work would get more simple, but if you have a big project it is not recommended to use the same id for different fields, but there is a simple way to solve that : Work with classes, you can create a class for a group of Input's which you will paste the text, one class for the buttons to paste the text and another class for the <p> you copy the text from, for that instead of "MyFunction you would just detect the click on the button class, if you want i can edit the example to show you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example:

```js
function Change(val){
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=val;


}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="book 1" id="myButton" onClick="Change(this.value)">Click</button>
<p id="test"></p>
```

How you can see, this function fill a `<p>` with value of button. you can do same for all(input,div etc.) .

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Test</TITLE>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      function testResults (form) {
      var TestVar1 = form.input[0].checked;
      var TestVar2 = form.input[1].checked;
        if (TestVar1 == true) {
          form.textbox.value = "Full Home Automation Package";
        } else if (TestVar2 == true){
          form.textbox.value = "Some Other Package";
        } else if (TestVar1 == false && TestVar2 == false) {
          form.textbox.value = "";
        }
      }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="POST">Choose a Service: <BR>
  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="input" VALUE="red" onChange="testResults(this.form)">Service 1<P>
  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="input" VALUE="blue" onChange="testResults(this.form)">Service 2<P>
  <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" VALUE="Click" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
  <P>Service Package Selected:</P> <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="textbox" NAME="selected" VALUE=""></div><p>

</FORM>
</BODY>
```